# Как установить часовой пояс на языке Си в Windows?

Tags: windows, c, время

Как здесь установить часовой пояс на +6? Там разность времени (td1) на 6 часов больше. Как по другому можно найти разность времени: мне нужен только часы и минуты?

```
#include <time.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
struct tm t,d,td;  
time_t t1,d1,td1;

t.tm_year=2013-1900;  
t.tm_mon=0;  
t.tm_mday=1;  
t.tm_hour=12;  
t.tm_min=32;  
t.tm_sec=30;  
t.tm_isdst=0;  
d.tm_year=2013-1900;  
d.tm_mon=0;  
d.tm_mday=2;  
d.tm_hour=13;  
d.tm_min=55;  
d.tm_sec=39;  
d.tm_isdst=0;

t1=mktime(&t);  
d1=mktime(&d);  
td1=d1-t1;  
printf(ctime(&t1));  
printf(ctime(&d1));  
printf(ctime(&td1));  
}
```

Comment: @Drakon, у Вас же был уже такой вопрос.

Полученную разницу в секундах (лучше вычислять td1 = labs(d1 - t1)) надо перевести в struct tm, вызывая **gmtime()**, а потом отнять от .tm_year 70 (это начало Epoch), а разность от часового пояса не зависит, главное, чтобы t1 и d1 были для одной TZ.

    td1 = *gmtime(&td1);
    td1.tm_year -= 70;

Потом можете брать любые поля из td1 (разность между датами t1 и d1 представленная в формате даты).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить время в формате `unix timestamp` и откорректировать как тебе надо

```
int current_time(int zone)
{
  int clock1 = 0;                   
  time_t rawtime;
  clock1 = time ( &rawtime );
  return clock1+zone*3600;  //zone - часовой пояс
}
```